# UTC and daylight savings - job schedule

Tags: azure-data-factory

For daylight savings time will an ADFV2 schedule update itself or do we need to go in there and update it when the time comes? I'm guessing the latter bc UTC doesn't change but I don't want to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF won’t handle daylight savings time automatically.

Here's a post using azure function and web activity to make it work. Maybe you could take a look.

http://www.aussierobsql.com/azure-data-factory-v2-handling-daylight-savings-p1/
http://www.aussierobsql.com/azure-data-factory-v2-handling-daylight-savings-p2/